# How to set name of the artifacts produced from Gradle to values passed from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: gradle, jenkins-pipeline, build.gradle

I am trying to setup a Jenkins pipeline to trigger builds using gradle for multiple environments.My requirement is that the artifacts produced when I run gradlew clean build should produce artifacts with name indicating the environment for which the pipeline was run. Example my-application-dev.jar

The value of the environment would be selected by the user when build will be triggered.
What is the optimal way to achieve this ? Does build allow to configure any such property via command line or do I need to define a task in my build.gradle and define properties within that task for which I will pass value from command line

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways.

The first one is to pass these naming-relevant pieces of information to the gradlew process, e.g. via -D or -P properties.
Then you need the Gradle build to be aware of these parameters and craft the artifact names it produces accordingly.

The second one is arguably better and more contained. You simply rename the artifacts produced by the gradlew command after it completes, in the Jenkinsfile. This works well if the pipeline decides what to do with these artifacts (e.g. publish to a repository) as opposed to the gradle script doing it (in which case you would most likely be better off using the first method).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @patrice-m. I tried to implement the first option to set it via gradle.
Defined a property archiveFileName and tried to use it within the copy task.

ext.archiveFileName
task copyReport(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir"
    into "$buildDir/artifacts"
    rename { String fileName ->
    fileName.replace('(.*).jar',archiveFileName)
    }
}

I try to pass the value of the property from the command line it does not work.(-P archiveFileName="test.jar"). It just creates the copy as archiveFileName. Am I using the property in incorrect manner inside the copy task?